# tips for a open id authentication wrapper for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, openid

i'm looking for a rails plugin for open id authentication.
I'm using restful-authentication

Can you tip me any plugin?
Do you know any tutorials for using these plugins?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the open_id_authentication plugin maintain by Rails core team http://github.com/rails/open_id_authentication

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this a few years ago, I had problems configuring Apache/mongrel. I vaguely remember with respect to Yahoo.

The plugin itself was easy to use!

Stephan